# How to make Dynamic commands in telegram

Tags: python, telegram

How do you send an id for items in the data base with out creating a method for each id

My goal is to type the id desired `/13` and the bot returns the info I need about that item

The repo of choice is [pyTelegramBotAPI](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI#types)

for database access and manipulation I am using flask-sqlalchemy

```
import telebot

from config import telegram_token       

bot = telebot.TeleBot(telegram_token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['summary'])
def send_welcome(message):
    summary = """ return general info about bot performance """
    bot.reply_to(message, summary )


@bot.message_handler(commands=['<id>'])
def send_welcome(message):
    id_ = """ return info about this id"""
    bot.reply_to(message, id_)
```

Comment: I don't know if `telebot` has `on_message` like `Discord` but if it has something similar then you can get full message and write own code to check what you get in message - instead of using `command`. Eventually you could check if it can use `regex` in `command`. And then you should check what you have in message content.

Comment: I checked your link to API and there is `@bot.message_handler(regexp="SOME_REGEXP")` which you could use with `regexp="\d+"` to get any number. And later you should use `message.text` to get this number as string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your link to API shows method with `regex` to recognize command

```
@bot.message_handler(regexp="SOME_REGEXP")
```

which you could use with `regexp="/\d+"` to get any `/number`.

And later you should use `message.text[1:]` to get this `number` as string (without `/`).

```
@bot.message_handler(regexp="/\d+")
def get_id(message):  
    id_ = message.text[1:]        # as string without `/`
    #id_ = int(message.text[1:])  # as integer
    bot.reply_to(message, id_)
```

---

**EDIT:**

To run function only for `/number` it needs also `^ $`

```
regexp="^/\d+$"
```

Without `^ $` it will run function also for `hello /13 world`

---

Minimal working code

```
import os
import telebot

TELEGRAM_TOKEN = os.getenv('TELEGRAM_TOKEN')

bot = telebot.TeleBot(TELEGRAM_TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(regexp="^\d+$")
def get_id(message):  
    id_ = message.text[1:]        # as string without `/`
    #id_ = int(message.text[1:])  # as integer
    bot.reply_to(message, id_)

bot.polling()
```

---

**EDIT:**

You can also use

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: ...)
```

like

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg: msg.text[0] == '/' and msg.text[1:].isdecimal())
def get_id(message):  
    id_ = message.text[1:]        # as string without `/`
    #id_ = int(message.text[1:])  # as integer
    bot.reply_to(message, id_)
```

or more readable

```
def is_number_command(message):
    text = message.text
    return text[0] == '/' and text[1:].isdecimal()
    
@bot.message_handler(func=is_number_command)
def get_id(message):  
    id_ = message.text[1:]        # as string without `/`
    #id_ = int(message.text[1:])  # as integer
    bot.reply_to(message, id_)
```

You can use `text[1:].isdecimal()` or `text[1:].isdigit()` or `text[1:].isnumeric()` or `str.isdecimal(text[1:])` or `str.isdigit(text[1:])` or `str.isnumeric(text[1:])`

With `func` you can use other functions to make it even more complex.

Comment: So it is basically using common python regex

Comment: I added example with `@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: ...)`

Comment: what is the difference between the two and what is more preferred for integers

Comment: differenece is they use different method to recognize digits in string - and there is no preffered method - use whatever you like.